# Performance difference between MOVE and = assignment in ABAP

Tags: abap

Is there any kind of performance gain between 'MOVE TO' vs x = y? I have a really old program I am optimizing and would like to know if it's worth it to pull out all the MOVE TO.  Any other general tips on ABAP optimization would be great as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is just the same operation expressed in two different ways. Nothing to gain there. If you're out for generic hints, [there's a good book available](https://www.sap-press.com/abap-performance-tuning_2092/) that I'd recommend studying in detail. If you have to optimize a specific program, use the tracing tools (transaction `SAT` in sufficiently current releases).

Answer (score 2):

The two statements are [equivalent](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/fc/eb3260358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm):

"
To assign the value of a data object source to a variable destination, use the following statement:

```
MOVE source TO destination.
```

or the equivalent statement

```
destination = source.
```

"

Answer (score 1):

No, they're the same.

Here's a couple quick hints from my years of performance enhancement:

1) if you use move-corresponding where possible, your code can be a lot more concise, modular, and extendable (in the distant past this was frowned upon but the technical reasons for this are generally not applicable anymore).

2) Use SAT at every opportunity, and be sure to turn on internal table tracking.  This is like turning on the lights versus stumbling over furniture in the dark.

3) Make the database layer do as much work as possible for you.  Try to combine queries wherever possible, especially when combining result sets.  Two queries linked by a join is usually much better than select > itab > select FOR ALL ENTRIES.

4) This is a bit advanced, but FOR ALL ENTRIES often has much slower performance than the equivalent select-options IN phrase.  This seems to be because the latter is built as one big query to the database layer while the former requires multiple trips to the database layer.  The caveat, of course, is that if you have too many records in your select-options the generated query at the database layer will exceed the allowable size on your system, but large performance gains are possible within that limitation.  In general, SAP just loves select-options.

5) Index, index, index!

Answer (score 1):

First of all move does not really affect much performance.

What is affecting quite a lot in the projects I worked for is following:

1. Nested loops (very evil). For example, loop through all documents, and for each document select single to check it company code is allowed to be displayed.
   Instead, make a list of company codes, consult them all once from db and consult this results table instead.
2. Use hash or sorted tables where possible. Where not possible, use standard table, but sort it by keys and use "binary search".
3. Select from DB by all key fields. If not possible, consider creating indexes.
   For small and simple selects, use joins. For bigger selects  using joins will still work faster, but would be difficult to follow up.
4. Minor thing - use field symbols to read table line, this makes it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be careful while using SELECT statement in ABAP language.
Unnecessary database connections significantly **decreases** the performance of ABAP program.

2) While using internal table with functions you should call it by reference to reduce memory usage.

*Call By Reference*:
Passes a pointer to the memory location.Changes made to the
variable within the subroutine affects the variable outside
the subroutine.

3)Should not use internal tables with workarea.

4)While using **nested loops**, use sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, as is the `ADD` keyword and `+` operator.

If you do want to optimize your ABAP, I have found the largest culprits to be:

- Not using binary lookups and/or (internal) table keys properly.
  The syntax of ABAP is brain-dead when it comes to table use. Know how
  to work with tables efficiently. Basically write
  better/optimal/elegant high-level code. This is always a winner!
- Fewer instructions == less time. The fewer instructions you hit the
  faster the program will run. This is important in tight loops... I
  know this sounds obvious, but ABAP is so slow, that if you are really
  trying to optimize critical programs, this will make a difference.
  (We have processes that run days... and shaving off an hour or so
  makes a difference!)
- Don't mix types. There is a little bit of overhead to some
  implicit conversions... for instance if you are initializing a
  `string` data type, then use the correct literal string with
  (backtick) quotes: `literal`. This also counts for looking up in
  tables using keys... use exact match datatypes.
- Function calls... I cannot stress the overhead of function calls
  enough... the less you have the better. Goes against anything a real
  computer programmer believes, but there you have it... ABAP is a
  special case.
- Loop using `ASSIGNING` (or `REF TO` - slightly slower on certain
  types), avoid INTO like a plague.

PS: Also keep in mind that `SWITCH` statements are just glorified `IF` conditionals... thus move the most common conditions to the top!

Answer (score 0):

You can create CDS with ADT Eclipse. Or views(se11) have good performance for selecting.

Answer (score 0):

"MOVE a TO" b and "a = b" are just same in ABAP. There is no performance difference "MOVE" is just a more visible, noticeable version.

But if you talk about "MOVE-CORRESPONDING", yes, there is a performance difference. It's more practical to code, but actually runs slower then direct movement.